# Passing Values from android to run in matlab

Tags: java, android, matlab, controls

I am in the process of making an android application that will ultimately need to pass a simple value or two to a computer (can be on the same network) that is running matlab script to control lights.
The passed value would have to be read in by Matlab and used in my case statements.  After researching various ways to go about this I am thoroughly confused... 
I found: http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24524-tcp-ip-communications-in-matlab
and

https://matlabideas.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/making-matlab-speak-to-another-matlab-to-my-android-or-to-any-other-machines/

but have had a hard time making sense of it all.  Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about those articles?

Comment: Not specifically.  I just thought that they might help someone best answer my question.  I understand a fair amount of what is going on with the first link however I'm not quite sure how to integrate that with Android.